# Installing dependencies using pip in a pre-packaged python install in Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pip, kivy

I am writing a python program to design test scripts using Kivy (a User Interface Library), SQLAlchemy (an ORM), and OpenPyXL (Integration with Excel).

On Ubuntu 14.04, the package installs are very straightforward as all of the libraries install to the system python using pip from the terminal.  The program compiles and runs without issue.

However, for Windows 7 & Windows 10, I am having difficulty installing the OpenPyXL Module.  This is because Kivy ships as a "Portable" distribution for Windows, which includes it's own instance of Python that is run instead of the system python.  The only other option is compiling Kivy from source.

SQLAlchemy can be downloaded with a setup-install.py script, and so I got that installed per the instructions I put up on github:

https://github.com/balex1/TestScriptBuilder

OpenPyXL only lists one installation method, however: pip.  So, I am trying to run pip to install OpenPyXL from the Kivy python.exe file.  Unfortunately, I see the same error every time.  Here's the command from my Windows 10 computer (the path is a bit different on the Windows 7 computer, but the error is the same):

```
C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x86\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x86\tools\pip.bat install openpyxl
```

The error returned is:

```
    ...\pip.bat, line 1
        python.exe -m pip %*
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

After doing some research, I thought I might be missing something in my PATH Environment Variable, so I tried adding:

```
C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x86\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip
```

to the environment variable, but this did not work.  I then tried adding the pip.exe file that I found in the Kivy Portable Python, but this also failed.

I tend to stick to Ubuntu, so I'm not quite sure where to move from here on the Windows platform.  Is there a way to fit the last piece into this puzzle or do I need to compile Kivy on Windows from source?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Sincerely,

Alex

Comment: python.exe obviously can't run a cmd.exe batch file. I would try `[absolute_path_to]\python.exe -m pip install openpyxl`.

Comment: That did it!  Looked at the documentation, this makes sense.  You have to use the -m flag to tell python to look for pip as a module.